# Below Python Script is not giving any result

Tags: python

I wrote the below python script in sublime text3 on executing it ( ctrl + B ) it is not giving any result.

Step 1:
Code:

```
class Avengers(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print('hello')
    avenger1 = Avengers()
    avenger1.__init__(self)
```

Step 2:

```
ctrl + B
```

Step 3:

Result:

***Repl Closed***

Comment: All you've done is define a class.  If you want to execute your `__init__` method, then you should create an instance of the class, e.g. `a = Avengers()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me fix the code

```
class Avengers(object):
 def __init__(self): 
    print('hello')
    avenger1 = Avengers()
    avenger1.init(self)
```

okay, here you creating a class called Avengers. why its not produce anything? because you never initialize that class (creating an object).

so here we go:

```
class Avengers(object):
 def __init__(self): 
    print('hello')
    avenger1 = Avengers()
    avenger1.init(self)

Avengers()
```

it will printing hello, but, its recursive. never end printing "hello". because each time that class is initialized, its creating an object again again and again. **init** is special function so, each time the class is initialized, **init** function will executed.

maybe what you want is like this:

```
class Avengers(object):
 def __init__(self): 
    print('hello')

Avengers()
```

additional reference that you can read: https://www.sololearn.com/Play/Python

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're only declaring a class, not instantiating it.
Your variable avenger1 exists within the **init** function, therefore it isn't being called. Indentation matters in python.

Try this:

```
class Avengers(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print('hello')
if __name__ == "__main__":
  avenger1 = Avengers()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating the class. Try something like:

```
class Avengers(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print('hello')
    avenger1 = Avengers()
    avenger1.__init__(self)

avengers = Avengers() # Initiates the class
```

When you instantiate a class like this, it will execute the `__init__` function for that class.

Comment: This code will cause an infinite loop, as the init function will result in another instantiation of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, but also note that Avengers class in its constructor is initializing another instance of Avengers.

This means when an Avengers object is created, it is creating another Avengers object which is creating another Avengers object and so on.

The `__init__` function is falling into an infinite recursion.

```
class Avengers(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print('hello')
    avenger1 = Avengers()   # this line triggers infinite recursion

    avenger1.__init__(self)

avengers = Avengers() # Initiates the class
```